# Is it possible to declare a Property type from a class for binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, binding, encapsulation

I wonder if it was possible to declare a `Property` in C#  to a custom `Class` type in order to Bind it to a WPF control ?

My concern is about the below case :

I have several `Properties` binded to a WPF View that must manage an updated member in the View and in the ViewModel.

My actual code is as below :

```
private string _oldBaudRate;
public bool HasPendingChange { get => _baudRate != _oldBaudRate; }
private string _baudRate;
public string BaudRate
{
    get => _baudRate;
    set
    {
        if (_baudRate == value)
            return;
        _baudRate = value;
        PropertyChanged(nameof(BaudRate));
    }
}
```

But to avoid repeating code I'd like to hide the following code management

```
private string _oldBaudRate;
public bool HasPendingChange { get => _baudRate != _oldBaudRate; }
private string _baudRate;
```

into a `Class MyPropertyExtended` then set the `Property` type of the latter like this :

```
public MyPropertyExtended<string> BaudRate;
```

then use `BaudRate.HasPendingChange` when I need it in code and bind also it to a WPF control.

Is there a means to achieve this ?

Comment: So basically you want to auto-implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to manage a secondary boolean member (not a property) that reflects if the actual value has changed regarding to its original value. As an example, suppose the end user change a field from 10 to 12, then changed member should return True. But if the end user changed again the value to the previous one 10, then the changed member will automatically update to False.

Comment: Where does the value 10 come from? Is it a value you hardcoded in your code? Or will it change at runtime as well?

Comment: 10 is an example parameter read from an external Device. The user can change this value in a DataGrid, and several events occurs when this value change. But if the user change the value back to the original device parameter, the Changed Property should be False.

Comment: So `MyPropertyExtended` just needs 3 properties then. One for the original value, one for the current value, and a `HasPendingChanges`. That'll work, won't it?

Comment: ... 10 change at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but the original value should be private and not a property. Moreover, I've a lot of properties of this kind and I'd like the hide this behind code in order to not have to rewrite it each time I add a new `MyPropertyExtended`.

Comment: You've already implemented it. But, the assignment operator in C# is not overridable. Are you ok with developers assigning to your properties only like BaudRate.Set(value) ? Because if yes, you have answered your own question. (Implement a setter and you are done). If you, however, are looking for a way to both let the developers of your API to assign to properties directly like `.BaudRate = value;`, unfortunately what you seek seems impossible.

Comment: _"Is it possible"_ is always too broad. You need to do some research, make an attempt, explain what _specifically_ you are having trouble with. All that said, you can achieve this basic goal by using some type of code-injection/aspect-oriented programming, like Postsharp. You will have to define custom relationships to allow the injected code to connect dependent properties to their dependencies.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I searched the Web but didn't found solution, but I think it's feasible. I'm still searching on my own. I shall only use free libraries or find free source code.

Comment: I add some research Tracks I'm searching on : custom extension method, custom XAML converter.